# Create Procedure not working

Tags: mysql

I am having problems creating a procedure that use a VIEW in MySQL, I have looked everywhere and it looks fine, but it doesn't work

This is my View, which is working fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_Ficha AS SELECT R.Id_rota, R.Tempo, R.Nome, F.Data, F.Tab_pesquisador_Id_pesquisador as Pes, 
F.Tab_municipio_Id_municipio as Mun, F.Tab_instrumento_Id_instrumento as Ins FROM Tab_ficha F LEFT JOIN Tab_rota AS R ON F.Tab_rota_Id_rota = R.Id_rota;
```

This is my Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_Ficha(IN id INT) 
BEGIN 
  IF id > 1 THEN 
    SELECT * FROM V_Ficha WHERE Id_rota = id;
  ELSE 
   SELECT 'Id must be greater than 0' AS Msg;
  END IF;
END;
```

I put the delimiters but it is still not working

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_Ficha(IN id INT) 
BEGIN
    IF (id > 1) THEN 
        SELECT * FROM V_Ficha WHERE Id_rota = id;
    ELSE 
        SELECT 'Id must be greater than 0' AS Msg;
    END IF;
END 
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: How doesn't it work?  Putting on my magic guessing cap, I'd say you need to read about `DELIMITER`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have changed your delimiter.  Otherwise whenever you have a ";" in your stored proc, MySql will think your stored proc is finished.

Change the delimiter before and after creating your stored proc.

Add this line before:

```
delimiter //
```

Add "//" at the end of your stored proc, then add this line after:

```
delimiter ;
```